# Awesome wm is unable to bring up any windows or a terminal

Tags: user-interface, awesome-wm

I just installed awesome wm and entered startx. The interface was brought up. I have the awesome background, the functional clock and tag list. but 'hotkey+enter' doesn't bring up a terminal window. Selecting the awesome logo in the top-left > 'open terminal' doesn't do anything either. Is there something else I need to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't have the default terminal installed. I believe it is `xterm`.

You can set the default terminal in the awesome WM config (`rc.lua`).

Comment: That was it. I thought this was installed by default. Many thanks.